# Putty: pscp file transfer change permission

Tags: putty, scp, chown, owner

I am transferring my file using pscp with the command below:

```
pscp target\app.war root@127.0.0.1:/jetty/webapps
```

What would be the syntax to change the `ownership` of the `app.war` file ?
In other words to perform `chown -R jetty:jetty` to the `app.war` using `pscp` ?

Something like:

```
pscp chown -R jetty:jetty root@127.0.0.1:/jetty/webapps/app.war
```

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: No such synatx - still in the wishlist: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/pscp-filemodes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with [pscp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pscp) which is an implementation of scp.

Perhaps you should look at [ssh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) or [plink](http://linux.die.net/man/1/plink) to remote in to the system and run a command e.g.

```
plink root@127.0.0.1 chown -R jetty:jetty /jetty/webapps/app.war
```

Notes:
The above is untested but you should be able to figure it out if it doesn't work.
For a single file you don't really need `-R`
It seems odd that you are scping to your localhost when a simple copy should do the trick.